# Assigning a value to the pointer to an object

Tags: class, pointers, c++14

```
   class Distance
   {
        public:
           int a;
   };
   int main()
    {
        Distance d1; //declaring object
        char *p=(char *)&d1;
        *p=1;
        printf("\n %d ",d1.a);
        return 0;
    }
```

This is my code.

When I am passing the value of **'a'** to be like **256,512** , I am getting **257,513** respectively but for values like **1000** i get **769** and for values like **16,128,100** I am getting **1**.

First I thought it might be related to powers of 2 being incremented by 1 due to changes in their binary representation. But adding 1 to binary representation of 1000 won't give me 769.

Please help me to understand this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*p = 1` sets the last byte(char) to `000000001`

As you're type casting int to char,
binary for `(int)1000` is `(binary)0000001111101000`
you're assigning `(int)1` for last 8 bits i,e `(binary)0000001100000001` which is `769`.

Using `256512` worked because last 8 bit that you change are all zeros i.e `(int)256512 is (binary)111110101000000000` so making last bit as 1 gives you `(binary)111110101000000001 which is (int)256513`

And I think(not sure) you get 1 for `16,128,100` because this integer is well out of int range and thus not assigned and a is set to `0` as class object is created. and thus setting last bit to 1 makes `a = 1`